# How to use early_command with ubiquity

Tags: system-installation, 16.04, ubiquity

I am trying to do some automatic installation and I need to run some commands as early as possible. So I modified my USB Installation medium (Ubuntu 16.04) and added:

```
menuentry "Install automatically" {
    set gfxpayload=keep
    linux   /casper/vmlinuz.efi file=/cdrom/auto.seed preseed/early_command=/cdrom/early.sh boot=casper auto=true automatic-ubiquity debug-ubiquity  quiet splash ---
    initrd  /casper/initrd.lz
}
```

this is explained here:
https://wiki.ubuntu.com/UbiquityAutomation
and here https://wiki.ubuntu.com/DesktopCDOptions

The file early.sh is on my USB stick as my auto.seed file (which is loaded just fine). But it seems my early.sh script is never run.

I just want to copy a file to the live system:

```
#!/bin/bash
cp /cdrom/wlan /root/etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/wlan;
chmod 0600 /root/etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/wlan;
```

I have prefixed it with /root as explained in the links above. I have even tried:

```
#!/bin/bash
touch /root/test
```

When I stop the installation before partman is running, I get the usual Live Desktop and I am expecting to open a console and see `/root/test`. But I don't.

I was looking at /var/log/syslog and I can see the boot parameters but no further log lines about early_command

My preseed file contains lines like this:

```
d-i preseed/early_command string in-target touch /root/test
```

How can I debug this situation? It is annoying to start over and over again.

Comment: Can you post your auto.seed file?

Comment: I added my preseed command

Answer (score 1):

I think with ubiquity early_command and late_command are simply not working. 
So now I am using something like

```
ubiquity  ubiquity/success_command string \
  cp /cdrom/script /target/root/; \
  chmod 0700 /target/root/script; \
  in-target /root/script; \
```

These commands work fine and I setup my wifi and do other fixes to my installation before reboot.