# 20.04: Why is there a ~10s grub delay, after menu selection, before kernel (no quiet arg) boot messages start?

Tags: boot, grub2, 20.04

- quiet kernel arg has been removed
- so after manual or auto grub menu selection, the kernel should start loading and posting messages
- instead there's a consistent ~10s delay with a blank screen
- the vmware drive light is lit during it, so it seems to be more than just waiting
- `dmesg --ctime` shows the timestamp of the first kernel message and it's after this delay
- 18.04 does not have this problem
- What is it doing?
- Is it needed?

  - If needed, can it be forced to post instead of a blank screen?
  - If not needed, can it be disabled?

grub config

```
GRUB_DEFAULT=0
GRUB_TIMEOUT_STYLE=menu
GRUB_TIMEOUT=2
GRUB_DISTRIBUTOR=`lsb_release -i -s 2> /dev/null || echo Debian`
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT=""
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX=""
```

Comment: Run `systemd-analyze blame` and see what it says.

Comment: Also what does `preseed` do? I suspect it could be cause of problem: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1219749/how-to-install-software-using-preseed-cfg-ubuntu-18-04-4

Comment: @WinEunuuchs2Unix Updated the question. This delay is right after grub, isn't that before systemd and services are started?

Comment: Yes systemd seems fine. So why did you install preseed and do any other preseed users complain about 10 second delay?

Comment: @WinEunuuchs2Unix removing find_preseed did not help. Is that GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX not the ubuntu 20.04 default?